# Reading from current buffer and using it in a function or command

Tags: vim

I'm trying to bind F5 to run `sass --update` on the current file. Where I'm stuck is the output. My decided solution is to include a comment of the output file in the first line of the input file, e.g.:
`//C:\Users\wuffie\Projects\output.css`
How can I read the line, trim the beginning slashes, and put it into my command? Will it require a full-fledged function? Here is what I have so far:
`au BufEnter,BufNew *.sass nmap <F5> :w<CR>:tabnew <bar> silent :r !sass --update expand('%:p'):`

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question but I strongly recommend using a preprocessor (like brunch or grunt on the command-line, or Prepros or Koala in GUI-land) for such things. The best part is that you don't need to configure anything in vim.

Comment: I agree whole heartily with @romainl on using a preprocessor/file watching tool. Sass even comes with its own watcher, e.g. [`sass --watch app/sass:public/stylesheets](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#using_sass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first clean up your command (I'm omitting the `:autocmd` for brevity; alternatively, you could place the `:map` into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sass.vim`, assuming the filetype is detected as `sass`):

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :w<Bar>tabnew<Bar>silent :r !sass --update %:p<CR>
```

- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- With the `<buffer>` keyword, the mapping is only defined for the file's buffer, not polluting other buffers.
- Use `<Bar>` everywhere, and add the missing concluding `<CR>`.
- The `expand()` wouldn't evaluate right, and it's not necessary, the `%:p` is interpreted by `:r` already. (But we'll need it with the extension, read on):

Now, let's build the reading of the first line into that:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :execute 'w<Bar>tabnew<Bar>silent :r !sass --update ' . expand('%:p') . ':' . getline(1)[2:]<CR>
```

This uses `:execute` to build the command-line, and `getline(1)` to access the first line of the file. I've using String indexing to cut off the first two comment characters (`[2:]`); you could also use `strpart()` here, or `substitute()` for more elaborate cases. To make this bulletproof, wrap that final expression in `shellescape(..., 1)`.

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :execute 'w<Bar>tabnew<Bar>silent :r !sass --update ' . shellescape(expand('%:p') . ':' . getline(1)[2:], 1)<CR>
```

Comment: The `:autocmd` can be "cleaned up" a bit by using`FileType` event, e.g. `autocmd FileType sass {command-here}`. Not to mention using the [`:augroup` and`:autcomd!` pattern](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html#clearing-groups). Although I prefer using the `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sass.vim` apparch over an autocmd as well.

Comment: Wow! Barely 15 minutes and already an answer. Thanks for all of this information, but one problem: I need to concatenate `%:p` before the `getline`, as well as put a colon between the two. It should come out as: `sass --update input:output`. Sorry for not clarifying in the question.